# Evolution Alarm Notifier and Calendar show wrong date format (US)

Tags: evolution, locale, calendar, date

- Ubuntu 23.04
- Language: United Kingdom (not American!)
- Formats: German

In both, drop down calendar and alarm notifier, I expect something like "24.12.2023" or "24/12/2023".

Instead: Both, drop down calendar and alarm notifier, show me "12/24/2023" which is extremely annoying, especially for dates like "2/1/2023" where nobody can distinguish between first of February or second of January.

Any idea how to repair that? I would also appreciate ISO date, i.e. "2024-12-24".

Addendum, as kindly requested:

- The program I used to configure language settings is called *Settings*.
- Results of the "locale" command:

  ```
   LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
   LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
   LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
   LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
   LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
   LC_ALL=
  ```
- Addendum 2: Content of file "/etc/default/locale":

  ```
   #  File generated by update-locale
   LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
   LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
   LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
   LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
  ```

And: It already had checked, but makes no difference when I change also the formats to United Kingdom.

Finally: Yes, I am totally right when I state that nobody can see if 1/2/1453 is 1. Feb or 2. Jan 1453, because the software does not tell if its date format is M/D/Y or D/M/Y. And this is exactly the idea of ISO, because 1453-02-01 is unambiguous.

Screenshots (Notice the reminders, on the left side, the same are also shown by the small notifier app. They show inconsistent behaviour, German weekdays, also in UK format mode, but US date format. May the Google account be the culprit? This is where the calendar is located):

Lang UK, Format DE
[image: Lang UK, Format DE]

Lang UK, Format UK
[image: Lang UK, Format UK]

Comment: Please also add to your question where you setup what - within the GUI, in the terminal?
The goal is to have an english language system, but German style number format, like 2.1.2024 for the date of "zweiter Januar 2024" and displaying number like 12.345,56 , so the point as the separator for thousands and the comma as the decimal separator?

Comment: Given the additional info you provided, the undesired date format seems to be due to some Evolution setting. (I don't use Evolution myself.)

Comment: I do not use it either, but some parts of it belong to Ubuntu and cannot be removed. So I think it's a malfunction of Ubuntu or at least these core parts of Evolution.

Comment: Hmm.. Then it's probably not Evolution. Can you please take a screenshot which demonstrates the issue, and add it to your question.

Comment: The "gnome-calendar" also acts inconsistently. On the left side "Freitag Dezember 1", which is Kauderwelsch (cauderwelsh), and for a single appointment "1 December" which might be UK format. I cannot make a screenshot of the last mentioned, because the PrtScr key is ignored while the menu is open, but I will try to take others.

Comment: Thunderbird is also connected with the same Google account and shows the same reminders, but with perfectly correct date and time format. For Ubuntu itself the Google account is added via the respective "Online Accounts" in the Settings app. Thunderbird has its own account management.

Comment: This is getting too complex for me. AFAIK it ought to use the date format in accordance with the `LC_TIME` environment variable. So yes, those date strings in the reminders may be created elsewhere. But I'm just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the malfunction has been solved with Ubuntu 23.10. The time is now 24H, and month and day are shown in the right order. However, the date format is still formatted the wrong way. It must be "11.2.2024", but in fact is "11/02/2024" which looks somewhat .. unpleasant .. but at least is no longer ambiguous.

Addendum: Maybe the program now evaluates LANGUAGE, but still ignores LC_TIME, so that the date format is now UK, not DE.

Comment: Did you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` to ensure the locales you want to use are properly generated?

Comment: All local settings are perfect, which can be seen in Thunderbird that behaves as expeced. I suppose that Evolution just ignores LC_TIME.